# storing multiple lines of output in ruby returned from shellout

Tags: ruby

I want to store a multi line output in ruby and i am not able to get the exact way for this.

Below is my use case:

> I am running a shell command in ruby as follows:
>
> ```
>  files = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('lsblk -o -d name --noheadings').run_command.stdout.split (/\n/)
>  puts "files value is '#{files}'
> ```
>
> "
>
> Here, the `lsblk` command in shell gives two rows as "vda and vdb" as
>   output, but when ran in ruby, it is displaying only first value i.e. vda

please let know if i am missing something here or is it like i should use some other structure to hold such multi line output from shell.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ **never** put a space between a function/method name and parentheses.

Comment: Is that command you're running malformed? When I execute `# lsblk -o --noheadings` I get `lsblk: unknown column: --noheadings`

Comment: Updated the code as per suggestion..still no luck ..am i missing something here..any help regarding this will be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

1) Fix your command. `lsblk -o --noheadings` returns `lsblk: unknown column: --noheadings`

2) Use `split()` not `strip ()`

3) Always use double-quotes for intra-string interpolation. Change `puts 'files value is #{files}'` to `puts "files value is #{files}"`

A working example would be:

```
files = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('lsblk').run_command.stdout.split(/\n/)
puts "files value is #{files}"
```

P.S. I like to use regex when matching new lines instead of strings. e.g. `split(/\n/)`